# Unable to Build apk after minifyEnabled true

Tags: android, proguard, android-proguard

I want to reduce APK size so I enabled `minifyEnabled`. After enabled `minifyEnabled` I got this error in gradle console and I do some changes in my `proguard-rules.pro` file

I don't want to use Twitter, Facebook, Exoplayer code at all but unable to how to let `proguard`  remove these code.

But still unable to build the apk:

```
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.google.firebase.database.connection.idl.zzaa { void zza(java.util.List,java.util.List,com.google.android.gms.dynamic.IObjectWrapper,long); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.google.android.gms.dynamic.IObjectWrapper'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.google.firebase.database.connection.idl.zzaa { void zzN(com.google.android.gms.dynamic.IObjectWrapper); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.google.android.gms.dynamic.IObjectWrapper'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.google.firebase.database.connection.idl.zzac { zzac(com.google.android.gms.internal.og); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.google.android.gms.internal.og'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.google.firebase.database.connection.idl.zzae { void zza(boolean,com.google.android.gms.internal.oh); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.google.android.gms.internal.oh'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.google.firebase.database.connection.idl.zzaf { zzaf(com.google.firebase.database.connection.idl.zzae,com.google.android.gms.internal.oh); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.google.android.gms.internal.oh'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.google.firebase.database.connection.idl.zzc { zzc(com.google.android.gms.internal.ok,com.google.android.gms.internal.wh,java.util.List,boolean,java.lang.String,java.lang.String); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.google.android.gms.internal.ok'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.google.firebase.database.connection.idl.zzc { zzc(com.google.android.gms.internal.ok,com.google.android.gms.internal.wh,java.util.List,boolean,java.lang.String,java.lang.String); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.google.android.gms.internal.wh'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.google.firebase.database.connection.idl.zze { com.google.firebase.database.connection.idl.zze zza(android.content.Context,com.google.firebase.database.connection.idl.zzc,com.google.android.gms.internal.oi,com.google.android.gms.internal.on); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.google.android.gms.internal.oi'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.google.firebase.database.connection.idl.zze { com.google.firebase.database.connection.idl.zze zza(android.content.Context,com.google.firebase.database.connection.idl.zzc,com.google.android.gms.internal.oi,com.google.android.gms.internal.on); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.google.android.gms.internal.on'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.google.firebase.database.connection.idl.zze { void zza(java.util.List,java.util.Map,com.google.android.gms.internal.ol,java.lang.Long,com.google.android.gms.internal.pe); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.google.android.gms.internal.ol'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.google.firebase.database.connection.idl.zze { void zza(java.util.List,java.util.Map,com.google.android.gms.internal.ol,java.lang.Long,com.google.android.gms.internal.pe); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.google.android.gms.internal.pe'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.google.firebase.database.connection.idl.zze { void zza(java.util.List,java.lang.Object,com.google.android.gms.internal.pe); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.google.android.gms.internal.pe'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.google.firebase.database.connection.idl.zze { void zza(java.util.List,java.lang.Object,java.lang.String,com.google.android.gms.internal.pe); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.google.android.gms.internal.pe'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.google.firebase.database.connection.idl.zze { void zza(java.util.List,java.util.Map,com.google.android.gms.internal.pe); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.google.android.gms.internal.pe'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.google.firebase.database.connection.idl.zze { void zzb(java.util.List,java.lang.Object,com.google.android.gms.internal.pe); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.google.android.gms.internal.pe'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.google.firebase.database.connection.idl.zze { void zzb(java.util.List,java.util.Map,com.google.android.gms.internal.pe); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.google.android.gms.internal.pe'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.google.firebase.database.connection.idl.zze { void zza(java.util.List,com.google.android.gms.internal.pe); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.google.android.gms.internal.pe'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.google.firebase.database.connection.idl.zze { com.google.firebase.database.connection.idl.zzag zza(com.google.android.gms.internal.pe); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.google.android.gms.internal.pe'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.google.firebase.database.connection.idl.zzf { zzf(com.google.firebase.database.connection.idl.zze,com.google.android.gms.internal.ol); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.google.android.gms.internal.ol'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.google.firebase.database.connection.idl.zzg { zzg(com.google.android.gms.internal.pe); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.google.android.gms.internal.pe'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.google.firebase.database.connection.idl.zzs { void setup(com.google.firebase.database.connection.idl.zzc,com.google.firebase.database.connection.idl.zzj,com.google.android.gms.dynamic.IObjectWrapper,com.google.firebase.database.connection.idl.zzv); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.google.android.gms.dynamic.IObjectWrapper'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.google.firebase.database.connection.idl.zzs { void listen(java.util.List,com.google.android.gms.dynamic.IObjectWrapper,com.google.firebase.database.connection.idl.zzp,long,com.google.firebase.database.connection.idl.zzag); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.google.android.gms.dynamic.IObjectWrapper'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.google.firebase.database.connection.idl.zzs { void unlisten(java.util.List,com.google.android.gms.dynamic.IObjectWrapper); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.google.android.gms.dynamic.IObjectWrapper'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.google.firebase.database.connection.idl.zzs { void put(java.util.List,com.google.android.gms.dynamic.IObjectWrapper,com.google.firebase.database.connection.idl.zzag); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.google.android.gms.dynamic.IObjectWrapper'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.google.firebase.database.connection.idl.zzs { void compareAndPut(java.util.List,com.google.android.gms.dynamic.IObjectWrapper,java.lang.String,com.google.firebase.database.connection.idl.zzag); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.google.android.gms.dynamic.IObjectWrapper'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.google.firebase.database.connection.idl.zzs { void merge(java.util.List,com.google.android.gms.dynamic.IObjectWrapper,com.google.firebase.database.connection.idl.zzag); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.google.android.gms.dynamic.IObjectWrapper'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.google.firebase.database.connection.idl.zzs { void onDisconnectPut(java.util.List,com.google.android.gms.dynamic.IObjectWrapper,com.google.firebase.database.connection.idl.zzag); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.google.android.gms.dynamic.IObjectWrapper'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.google.firebase.database.connection.idl.zzs { void onDisconnectMerge(java.util.List,com.google.android.gms.dynamic.IObjectWrapper,com.google.firebase.database.connection.idl.zzag); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.google.android.gms.dynamic.IObjectWrapper'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.google.firebase.database.connection.idl.zzu { void setup(com.google.firebase.database.connection.idl.zzc,com.google.firebase.database.connection.idl.zzj,com.google.android.gms.dynamic.IObjectWrapper,com.google.firebase.database.connection.idl.zzv); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.google.android.gms.dynamic.IObjectWrapper'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.google.firebase.database.connection.idl.zzu { void listen(java.util.List,com.google.android.gms.dynamic.IObjectWrapper,com.google.firebase.database.connection.idl.zzp,long,com.google.firebase.database.connection.idl.zzag); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.google.android.gms.dynamic.IObjectWrapper'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.google.firebase.database.connection.idl.zzu { void unlisten(java.util.List,com.google.android.gms.dynamic.IObjectWrapper); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.google.android.gms.dynamic.IObjectWrapper'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.google.firebase.database.connection.idl.zzu { void put(java.util.List,com.google.android.gms.dynamic.IObjectWrapper,com.google.firebase.database.connection.idl.zzag); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.google.android.gms.dynamic.IObjectWrapper'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.google.firebase.database.connection.idl.zzu { void compareAndPut(java.util.List,com.google.android.gms.dynamic.IObjectWrapper,java.lang.String,com.google.firebase.database.connection.idl.zzag); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.google.android.gms.dynamic.IObjectWrapper'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.google.firebase.database.connection.idl.zzu { void merge(java.util.List,com.google.android.gms.dynamic.IObjectWrapper,com.google.firebase.database.connection.idl.zzag); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.google.android.gms.dynamic.IObjectWrapper'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.google.firebase.database.connection.idl.zzu { void onDisconnectPut(java.util.List,com.google.android.gms.dynamic.IObjectWrapper,com.google.firebase.database.connection.idl.zzag); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.google.android.gms.dynamic.IObjectWrapper'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.google.firebase.database.connection.idl.zzu { void onDisconnectMerge(java.util.List,com.google.android.gms.dynamic.IObjectWrapper,com.google.firebase.database.connection.idl.zzag); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.google.android.gms.dynamic.IObjectWrapper'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.google.firebase.database.connection.idl.zzv { void zza(java.util.List,com.google.android.gms.dynamic.IObjectWrapper,boolean,long); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.google.android.gms.dynamic.IObjectWrapper'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.google.firebase.database.connection.idl.zzv { void zza(java.util.List,java.util.List,com.google.android.gms.dynamic.IObjectWrapper,long); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.google.android.gms.dynamic.IObjectWrapper'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.google.firebase.database.connection.idl.zzv { void zzN(com.google.android.gms.dynamic.IObjectWrapper); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.google.android.gms.dynamic.IObjectWrapper'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.google.firebase.database.connection.idl.zzx { void zza(java.util.List,com.google.android.gms.dynamic.IObjectWrapper,boolean,long); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.google.android.gms.dynamic.IObjectWrapper'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.google.firebase.database.connection.idl.zzx { void zza(java.util.List,java.util.List,com.google.android.gms.dynamic.IObjectWrapper,long); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.google.android.gms.dynamic.IObjectWrapper'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.google.firebase.database.connection.idl.zzx { void zzN(com.google.android.gms.dynamic.IObjectWrapper); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.google.android.gms.dynamic.IObjectWrapper'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId { com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId getInstance(com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.google.firebase.messaging.zzc { void zza(com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurement,android.content.Context,java.lang.String,com.google.android.gms.internal.aee,com.google.firebase.messaging.zzb,int); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.google.android.gms.internal.aee'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.google.firebase.messaging.zzc { java.lang.Object zza(com.google.android.gms.internal.aee,java.lang.String,com.google.firebase.messaging.zzb); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.google.android.gms.internal.aee'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.google.firebase.messaging.zzc { android.os.Bundle zza(com.google.android.gms.internal.aee); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.google.android.gms.internal.aee'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.google.firebase.messaging.zzc { java.lang.String zza(com.google.android.gms.internal.aee,com.google.firebase.messaging.zzb); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.google.android.gms.internal.aee'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.twitter.sdk.android.core.identity.TwitterLoginButton { void setCallback(com.twitter.sdk.android.core.Callback); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.twitter.sdk.android.core.Callback'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.twitter.sdk.android.core.services.MediaService { retrofit2.Call upload(okhttp3.RequestBody,okhttp3.RequestBody,okhttp3.RequestBody); }', but not the descriptor class 'okhttp3.RequestBody'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.twitter.sdk.android.core.services.MediaService { retrofit2.Call upload(okhttp3.RequestBody,okhttp3.RequestBody,okhttp3.RequestBody); }', but not the descriptor class 'okhttp3.RequestBody'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.twitter.sdk.android.core.services.MediaService { retrofit2.Call upload(okhttp3.RequestBody,okhttp3.RequestBody,okhttp3.RequestBody); }', but not the descriptor class 'okhttp3.RequestBody'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.twitter.sdk.android.core.services.SearchService { retrofit2.Call tweets(java.lang.String,com.twitter.sdk.android.core.services.params.Geocode,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.Integer,java.lang.String,java.lang.Long,java.lang.Long,java.lang.Boolean); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.twitter.sdk.android.core.services.params.Geocode'
Note: there were 1 references to unknown classes.
      You should check your configuration for typos.
      (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unknownclass)
Note: there were 122 unkept descriptor classes in kept class members.
      You should consider explicitly keeping the mentioned classes
      (using '-keep').
      (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#descriptorclass)
Note: there were 21 unresolved dynamic references to classes or interfaces.
      You should check if you need to specify additional program jars.
      (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#dynamicalclass)
Note: there were 24 accesses to class members by means of introspection.
      You should consider explicitly keeping the mentioned class members
      (using '-keep' or '-keepclassmembers').
      (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#dynamicalclassmember)

Warning: there were 26 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
         You may need to add missing library jars or update their versions.
         If your code works fine without the missing classes, you can suppress
         the warnings with '-dontwarn' options.
         (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedclass) ***




-printseeds seeds.txt
-printusage unused.txt
-printmapping mapping.txt

-keepattributes *Annotation*
-dontwarn java.lang.invoke.*
-dontwarn **$$Lambda$*
-dontwarn com.google.android.exoplayer2.**
-dontwarn com.devbrackets.**
-dontwarn com.facebook.**
-dontwarn com.twitter.**
-dontwarn okhttp3.**
-dontwarn com.twitter.sdk.android.core.services.params.Geocode
-keep class com.google.firebase.messaging.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.**
-keep class com.google.firebase.database.connection.** { *; }
-keep class com.example.gurtek.desireme.circlemenu.CircleMenu
-keep class com.example.gurtek.desireme.imagezoom.ImageViewTouchBase
```

Answer (score 0):

i got the solution actually i'm trying to solve notes instead of warning in console. After Solving warning apk build just fine